# Binding toolkit: GestureListener events to methods in view model

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, model-binding

In a Windows Phone 7.5 project, is there a way to bind

```
<toolkit:GestureListener DoubleTap="GestureListener_DoubleTap"/>
```

directly to a view model method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might need the EventToCommand behavior. Alternatively you could roll your own behaviors with touch event handler command properties or attached dependency properties of type ICommand that handle the events. Depending on preference.